# Convert location coordinates from long to decimal degree

Tags: c, gps, latitude-longitude

I have a GPS module which gives location in long, i am trying to find formula to convert it into decimal degree with precision 6. For example, GPS module gives latitude as 46562136(12° 56' 2.13" N) and longitude 279699970(77° 41' 39.97" E) which they derived from ddmm.mmmm format using the formula:

```
((dd* 3600000) + ((mm*10000  +  mmmm)* 6))).
```

(I do not have these values returned in ddmm.mmmm format, GPS module only gives 46562136 and 279699970). Now how to convert this long value to decimal degrees?

Comment: Isn't it just `value / 36e5`? E.g. 46562136 / 36e5 is approximately 12.93392667.

Comment: ...and the remainder 0.93392667 × 60 = 56.0356002. And *that* remainder  0.0356002 × 60 = 2.136012 giving the 12° 56' 2.13".

Comment: The other is 279699970 / 36e5 = 77.69443611, and the remainder 0.69443611 × 60 = 41.66616667. And *that* remainder 0.66616667 × 60 = 39.97 giving the 77° 41' 39.97".